# cURL не редиректит сайт

Tags: php, curl, redirect

Мне нужно сохранить данные из формы, а затем отправить пользователя на оплату в банк, делаю вот так:

```
$url="http://site.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; Content-Length:".strlen($postData).";"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
$html=curl_exec($ch);
if (FALSE === $html)
  throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
$redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
```

Я так полагаю (потому что с cURL ранее особо дела не имел) должен произойти редирект на целевую страницу, но вместо этого возвращается просто содержимое страницы. Настроек safe_mode и open_basedir на сервере нет. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Curl работает на стороне сервера. Вам, насколько я понял - надо редиректить в банк клиента (т.е. браузер). Для этого надо отправить браузеру заголовок: header("Location: YOUR_URL");

Comment: Не могу, так как нужно отправлять еще и данные через POST. Было принято решение вместо cURL генерировать форму и отправлять ее посредством JavaScript.

Comment: Если вам надо затащить post на страницу оплаты, почему просто не отправлять туда $_post ?

Answer (score 0):

Как сказали в комментариях нужно сделать отправку пользователя через header

```
header("Location: http://www.host.ru"); 
exit();
```

Обращаю внимание, что до header не должно быть никаких выводов на экран иначе будут ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Очень похожей задачей занимался недавно. Тоже пытался через `curl` - данные отправляются в банк, но браузер не переходит. По прошествии времени понял довольно простую вещь - `curl` выполняется на сервере и браузером управлять не может.

Решение сложилось такое. Получаю данные от пользователя в своей форме (на клиентском сайте магазин на WooCommerce). Обрабатываю эти данные в своем плагине платежного шлюза (включая сформированную в моем коде цифровую подпись). Отправляю get-запрос (просто редирект) на страницу своего сайта с параметрами для банка. Браузер уходит по этому адресу. Принимаю запрос на своем сайте, на лету в php генерирую форму с данными для банка вместе со скриптом, который "нажимает" в ней `submit`. Браузер переходит на страницу оплаты в банке по `POST`.

Функция по формированию формы и ее отправке - ниже.

```
function check_for_sdm() {
    if( isset($_GET['sdm_gateway']) ) {
        $action = $_GET['sdm_gateway'];
        if ($action == 'post') {
            if (isset($_GET['sdm_mode']))
                $sdm_mode = $_GET['sdm_mode'];
            else
                $sdm_mode = '';
            if ($sdm_mode == 'test')
                $gateway_link = 'https://3dst.sdm.ru/cgi-bin/cgi_link';
            else
                $gateway_link = 'https://3ds.sdm.ru/cgi-bin/cgi_link';
            ?>
                <form id="sdm_form" action="<?php echo $gateway_link; ?>" method="post">
                <?php
                    foreach ($_GET as $a => $b) {
                        if (($a !== 'sdm_gateway') && ($a !== 'sdm_mode')) {
                            $input = '<input type="hidden" name="'.htmlentities($a).'" value="'.htmlentities($b).'">';
                            echo $input;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.getElementById('sdm_form').submit();
                </script>
            <?php
            die();
        }
    }
}
```